# can not receive mail by own created mail from gmail

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, mail-server

I want to create my own mail ID like `myname@mydomain.in` instead of paying extra to google for extra mail ids as I have already `myname@mycompany.in`.

Things I have are `mydomain.in`(I paid for this domain name and this domain.in is pointing to our staging server say IP xx.xx.xx.xx), system with Ubuntu server.

I tried setup Postfix,  when install Postfix server

```
Internet site:  mydomain.in.
Root and postmaster mail recipient: root
mydestinations:  mydomain.in, localhost.example.com, localhost
```

rest all default.

Now I am able to send mail from postfix mail server by command `$ sendmail myname@gmail.com 'message'`. I checked `myname@gmail.com` I got mail from `root@mydomain.in`. I try reply to `root@mydomain.in` from `myname@gmail.com` but there is no mail received under root. This is the file in ubuntu server `/var/mail/root` where mails received, it is empty.

I want if someone send mail to `root@mydomain.in` should be saved in ubuntu server.

Please let me know if you don't understand my question.

**EDIT:**

There is no MX in `mydomain.in`. I did `dig mx mydomain.in`. where should I set MX whether in staging server or in `bigrock.in` where we bought this name from.

Result of `dig mx mydomain.in` is `;;QUESTION SECTION: mydomain.in IN MX ;;AUTHORITY SECTION: mydomain.in 7200 IN SOA dns1.bigrock.in. 201...3 7200 7200`.

Result of telnet `mydomain.in 25` gives `Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...` I guess port 25 in staging server is blocked by firewall. I need to contact my admin to allow port 25.

**Update:**

I get failure notice to my gmail account back

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     fmaster@mydomain.in

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain mydomain.in by us2.mx2.mailhostbox.com. [208.91.199.202].

The error that the other server returned was:
550-5.1.1 <fmaster@mydomain.in>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual alias table
550 5.1.1 Please see http://support.mailhostbox.com/email-administrators-guide/error-codes for explanation of the problem.
```

Comment: Many ISPs block port 25, so you can use port 587 as an alternative, or secure SMTP on port 465

Answer (score 0):

If it hasn't an MX, then it should have an A. If haven'tany of them, how could gmail find out the ip address of the receiver mailserver?